# CLang to convert c++ pointer/reference variables to wrapper objects in some other language

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to convert all c++ pointer/reference variables into wrapper objects in some other language (say C#). What approach should I follow? I am not very much familiar with clang's source code. And there is no appropriate documentation available either. What options clang provides me in order to achieve my objective?

Comment: Are you trying to convert C++ source code to C# source code?

Comment: Something like that. Actually I already (manually) converted one C++ project to C#. But (foolishly) used pointer variables as normal objects. Now, I want a list of pointer variables in C++ project, by which I can refactor my C# objects (already created) into some sort of wrappers, like `String str="";` to `List<String> str; str[0]="";`